# Getting the index of video elements and applying to function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 video elements on a page that will or wont be displayed based on viewport size.
Each of these will have their own play button which triggers a number of functions that are using an index to target a specific player. I'm wondering if there is a better way if iterating through the play buttons and then applying the correct index?

```
$(window).resize(function () {
    if ($(this).width() > 768) {
        $(".toggle-1").on("click", function () {
            playPause(0);
            anotherFun(0)
        });
    } else {
        $(".toggle-2").on("click", function () {
            playPause(1);
            evenMoreFun(1)
        });
    }
});
```

```
function playPause(index) {
    // player[index].togglePlay();
}
function anotherFun(index) {
    // code[index]
    // more stuff
}
function evenMoreFun(index) {
    // code[index]
    // more stuff
}
```

Comment: Pass `ID`s instead of the index? and work with them from there. The ID won't change whether a video is visible or not, If I understood your question correctly. Hope this helps.

Comment: @Yuniac could you provide an example?

Comment: Sure, check my answer. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `ID`s instead of indexies:

```
$(window).resize(function () {
    if ($(this).width() > 768) {
        $(".toggle-1").on("click", function () {
            playPause("vid1");
            anotherFun("vid1")
        });
    } else {
        $(".toggle-2").on("click", function () {
            playPause("vid2");
            evenMoreFun("vid2")
        });
    }
});



function playPause(id) {
    const element = document.getElementByID(id)
    element.togglePay()
}
function anotherFun(id) {
    const element = document.getElementByID(id)
    // do stuff on element
}
function evenMoreFun(id) {
    const element = document.getElementByID(id)
    // do stuff on element
}
```

Just make sure that you pass the `ID` as a string in your `playPause` and `anotherFun`